# DL: when a prediction SHOULD be considered false in a multiclass multilabel problem

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, metrics

I am currently working on getting the metrics (classification report, confusion matrix) for a DL problem and I have stumbled across a problem.

My y_true is something like [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0] (multilabel). The ones indicating the correct values (eg. RED, BLUE, GREEN).

My model outputs with Sigmoid activation, getting everything between 0 and 1. So far so good.

Now, the way I proceed is by getting the max value/score of the prediction `torch.max(outputs)`, then its index/position on the array and then 1-hot encoding it so to resemble the y_true.

My question is, if y_true has 2 or more ones (labels), then even if I manage to predict 1 of them right, my 1-hot encoding will be always false (cause [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0] <> [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]). I could get more than 1 score, but again I don't know how many labels my y_true has every time.

What is the right way to proceed with this?

Comment: So, in Your example, can one datapoint belong to 3 different classes at once? Usually, "multilabel" means "can have more than two labels", but Your case seems like "can have more than two labels AT ONCE"

Comment: My problem is multi-class (meaning I have more than 2 classes to choose from) and multi-label (meaning my item can be 1 or more classes at once). Let's say I have an image which can belong to 10 different colors (multi-class) and simultaneously has more than 1 color in it (for example blue, green and red)